# Jasmine testing for a guess the number function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to StackOverflow and was hoping to clear a doubt I have with regards to Jasmine testing for the following:

I have a JavaScript function called guessTheNumber where the secretNumber is set to 4 (data type is number).

Would it be correct to input the number as a string and expect the result to be successful for my test to pass case? Is that the correct way to go about unit testing your function?

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: The code consists of a function checking the number i.e. in an integer format. I wanted to use jasmine and perform unit testing. My question it, in order to achieve a successful test to pass, must I test the numbers in a string format as well? Is that how testing should be i.e. where in the correct numbers must pass in any format? If yes, I will have to modify my function accordingly.